# How to set text in Text programmatically in a function component in react native form validation?

Tags: react-native

I want to display an error message if the mobile and password fields are empty.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const login = (m, p) => {

  if (m == "" || p == "") {
     setMessage('mobile & password both are required')
     return false;
  } else 
  {
      return true;
  }
}
 const App: () => React$Node = () => {

   const [mobile, setMobile] = useState('');
   const [pass, setPass] = useState('');
   const [errorMessage, setMessage] = useState('');

   return (
     <>
        <Text style={{ marginTop: 150 }}>
            { errorMessage }
        </Text>
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={mobile => setMobile(mobile)}
          defaultValue={mobile} />

        <TextInput 
          onChangeText={pass => setPass(pass)}
          defaultValue={pass} />

        <Button
            title="Login"
            onPress={() => {login(mobile,pass)}}
        />
     </>
   );
  };
```

When I press the login button I get this error message:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: setMessage
```

Can anyone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `login() function` from outside the hook function. and `setMessage` is not available **outside hooks function App**

Do like below:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';


 const App: () => React$Node = () => {

   const [mobile, setMobile] = useState('');
   const [pass, setPass] = useState('');
   const [errorMessage, setMessage] = useState('');

   const login = (m, p) => {

     if (m == "" || p == "") {
        setMessage('mobile & password both are required')
        return false;
     } else {
      return true;
     }
   }

   return (
     <>
        <Text style={{ marginTop: 150 }}>
            { errorMessage }
        </Text>
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={mobile => setMobile(mobile)}
          defaultValue={mobile} />

        <TextInput 
          onChangeText={pass => setPass(pass)}
          defaultValue={pass} />

        <Button
            title="Login"
            onPress={() => {login(mobile,pass)}}
        />
     </>
   );
 };
```

then you can export it, if you want to use it somewhere else like below:

```
export default App;
```

If you need to keep `login()` outside for some reason then you can use like this:

```
export const login = (m, p, setMessage) => { 
   if (m == "" || p == "") {
     setMessage('mobile & password both are required')
     return false;
   } else {
     return true;
   }
}
```

then when calling the `login function` pass the `setMessage` like below:

```
<Button
     title="Login"
     onPress={() => {login(mobile, pass, setMessage)}}
/>
```

Comment: I want a different solution because I want to do `export const login..` for jest testing.

Comment: @BoidurjaTalukdar,  edited see my answer again, please up it and mark it as solved. thanks